# What is the purpose of typing <widget> after children in flutter? do I need to use it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

example use case:

```
home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Quiz App'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[],
      )
  )
```

However this will also output the exact same thing with:

```
home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Quiz App'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [],
      )
  )
```

Most of the guides says to put the `<widget>` after children but What is the exact purpose of it? do i need to include it everytime?

Comment: I suggest you go through this https://dart.academy/generics-in-dart-and-flutter/#:~:text=Flutter%20code%20uses%20Dart%20generics,one%2C%20while%20remaining%20type%20safe.

Comment: I can kind of understand what the use of `<widget>` is already but the question I wanted to know is since it also works without adding `<widget>` do i need to use it everytime?

Comment: No, you do not need to use it everytime. In most situation it is not necessary. In some situation, like a `FutureBuilder<T>` you can opt to provide a `T` to make your life a bit easier, but that too is completely options. When it is actually mandatory for you to provide a type generic, Dart will notify you of the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's optional.
Row and Column are two of the most commonly used layout patterns.
Row and Column - each take a list of child widgets.

```
List<Widget> Selections = [
   SelectedColor(),
   SelectedOption(),
 ];

body: Row(children: Selections),
```

And as Row, Column and Stack are specially designed as a layout patterns, by default it takes Widgets as its children so it works without  keyword also.